# Hibernate Tool - hibernate-mapping

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate tool with eclipse ganymede 3.4.1. Now when I create the .hbm.xml file using the code generation of Hibernate tool, it is automatically creating a composite key.

I am adding the code over here:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Employee" table="Employee" catalog="mytest">
        <composite-id name="id" class="EmployeeId">
            <key-property name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="name" type="string">
                <column name="name" length="30" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

but I need a mapping something like:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Employee" table="Employee" catalog="mytest">
       
            <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="id" />
            </id>
            <key-property name="name" type="string">
                <column name="name" length="30" />
            </key-property>
            </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: We should close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736939/hibernate-tool-with-eclipse-ganymede instead

Answer (score 1):

The tool somehow got that your table structure has a composite primary key (id, name). If this is the table structure than the tool didn't got it wrong. Or maybe it just has a bug.

Anyway if you to have a unique index on the "name" field you should map it like:

```
<property name="name" type="string" unique="true">
    <column name="name" length="30"/>
</property>
```

`<key-property>` tag is used in `<composite-id>` tag to define multiple properties as identifier properties.